# Overall low computer usage but entire pc is laggy

Tags: windows-10, performance

I did "reset to factory settings" and now my entire pc is laggy. Everything works so slow (minecraft will be indicator here). Before this reset I have decent fps (around 50 / 60) with normal settings. Now I have terrible fps (10, max 20) with lowest possible settings. I saw a post where guy told sth about Page Fault - with around 30mins uptime I have 20 000 000 on anydesk.exe (w/o anydesk it was lagged too) and the same amount on dwm.exe. For addition I saw CPU clock stuck at 499mhz (no stresstest yet).

It seems to me like HDD is "broken", but tested it with HDTune and it's fine.

Temperatures are fine too.

Win10 x64 Home edition (doesnt know exact version, I will check and edit it later within 12h)
Dell Inspiron 3543, 4gb, I5 5200u, gtx 920m and integrated 5500.

Comment: I take it you already downloaded and installed all the Dell drivers? Go to dell website, search for your particular Dell service tag and download the drivers there. Or if they have Dell Update - use that (saves you from doing the manual work)

Comment: Yeah did it. I didnt updated the bios cuz Im scared and imo it's not the issue here (cuz it's worked good before reset).

Comment: Instead of HD Tune, try the Dell Hardware Diagnostics App to see what it says about all the hardware. I use Lenovo and do not hesitate to keep BIOS up to date.

Comment: I used it too, literally didnt found anything. It has drivers checking thing too and again - didnt found anything.

Comment: If all the hardware is working, there is a chance the factory reset did not go properly. Do it again, or, use the Microsoft Media Creation link Repair Install and Keep NOTHING. (Make certain all your data is backed up - you would have done that for the first factory reset.

Comment: Ok I will do "Upgrade this PC" and Keep Nothing from Media Creation Tool and I will let You know.

Comment: Before I do Fresh Installation I did OCCT CPU StressTest, and frequency doesnt change, still 499mhz. Trying to do Fresh Installation but "preparing" is so slow

Comment: Reinstall doesnt fix the problem. Still - utilization = 100% and Clocks stucks at 499mhz (sometimes 479mhz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an weird fix. Charger was connected in but it doesnt charge an battery (windows knows that charger is connected, but there was not "charging"). Disconnected and connected charger to the laptop, battery changed it's state to Charging and CPU's clocks went instantly to 2.6ghz. Thank You for ur time.